# This problem can be solved graphically, but can it be solved mathematically?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> [image]

I can solve it graphically, but not mathematically. Graphically, I found X and Y to be equal, X = Y = 1.33

Comment: The image is not to scale

Comment: Please formulate the problem out in the body. If you are not yet familiar with MathJax , no problem , someone will edit the question.

Comment: Seems like a time for the law of sines.

Comment: @Peter Very little need for MathJax here. It is yet incapable of drawing figures.

Comment: Just use Pythagoras theorem and the angle bisector theorem.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Right, the drawing is not to scale. This is how the problem was presented online. But from the information, an accurate representation of the problem can be drawn. I drew many possible hypotenuses until I found one where |BD| = y + 1, where |CD| = 1 unit; the 1 in y+1 remains unchanged in each ‘test’ hypotenuse. Only the value of y and x change until the the requirement |BD| = y + 1 is met. I guess this approach is very unorthodox… but it demonstrates such a triangle is possible. Initially, I wasn’t sure the problem was ‘legit.’

Comment: @Vin Good, good, so my comment was superfluous. I will think about if I have something more useful to tell you. Hopefull I will be back soon.

Comment: Hmmm using Mick's hint you get a relation between x and y, and then drawing a line from D perpendicular to x to get two more right angled triangles (where you can do some more pythagorassing) you get a second relation between x and y. But solving this for x and y looks horrendous at first sight. I don't think $x$ and $y$ are truly equal tbh

Comment: [You asked this question yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4562584/409), and it was closed for lack of context. Deleting-and-reposting is not appropriate. Rather, you should edit the original version to improve its quality in hopes of attracting re-open votes. (Maybe those of us who also had our comments deleted can re-add them. :)

Comment: @Blue: What sort of context would you suggest? It looks like a simply stated  problem. As explained above, the illustration is proportionally incorrect; but when properly drawn, it looks very similar to the triangle above.

Comment: @Vin: The community can be finicky, so it's hard to say what would attract re-open votes. However, some common ideas: Say where you got the problem and why it interests you. (Was it a tricky homework question? an online challenge you're determined to solve? etc) Mention (as you did in comments before) that your graphical soln came from using CAD to draw an accurate figure. Perhaps most importantly: Say something about what you've tried algebraically and where you got stuck. This shows your investment in a solution as well as your level of knowledge, which helps people tailor their responses.

Comment: @Vin: Also, give the question a descriptive title. I suggest something like "In $\triangle ABC$, the bisector at right angle $A$ meets $BC$ at $D$. If $CD=1$ and $BD=AD+1$, then ...". Don't make people have to click-into a problem to know what it's about. (This also helps future people doing site searches.) ... BTW, you can also say that someone (that would be me :) commented before that $x=\sqrt[4]{3}$, to give a sense that the problem isn't exactly trivial.

Comment: @Vin: Oh, and post to the ["Request for reopen votes"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34447/409) item in Meta to call attention to your updated question.

Comment: What do you mean you "solved it graphically"?

Comment: @Blue: I’ll have to consider re-editing my verbiage. The ‘system’ didn’t like that I did too many edits to my original; at certain point the ‘system’ said my IP address had accessed the problem (or the site) too many times; and instructed me try again on the next day. Your suggested title change seem too wordy; is that a typical type of title?

Comment: @Vin: Wordy titles are good. Consider the future: Someone (maybe you) is looking for that fascinating question of yours that they only vaguely remember, or maybe they saw the same question in an online forum and want to know if it's been asked here already. A site search can bring up dozens or even hundreds of results. Titles like "Capable people failed to solve this problem" and "This problem can be solved graphically" are no help whatsoever for getting this someone to their target question. Give titles that help! :) ... Your "system" problems don't excuse circumventing closure by reposting.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ t = \angle ABC $

then

$ x = (y + 2) \sin t  $

$ x = 1 \cdot \sin t + y \cos 45^\circ = \sin t + y \cos 45^\circ $

$ \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{(y+1)}{(y + 2) \cos t } $

The last equation becomes

$ x(y + 1) = (y + 2) \cos t $

Use the first equation,

$  (y+1) (y+2) \sin t = (y+2) \cos t $

So

$\tan t = \dfrac{1}{y+1} $

It follows that

$ \cos t = \dfrac{y+1}{\sqrt{y^2 + 2 y + 2 }} $

$ \sin t = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y^2 + 2 y + 2 }} $

Substitute into the second equation,

$\dfrac{y + 2}{\sqrt{y^2 + 2 y + 2}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+ 2 y + 2}} + \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{2}} $

And this simplifies to

$ y + 2 = 1 + \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{y^2 + 2 y + 2} $

And further to

$ \sqrt{2} (y + 1) = y \sqrt{ y^2 + 2 y + 2} $

So that

$ 2 (y^2 + 2 y + 1) = y^2 (y^2 + 2 y + 2 ) $

And finally,

$ y^4 + 2 y^3 - 4 y - 2 = 0 $

whose solution is (from wolframalpha.com)

$ y = \dfrac{1}{2} (-1 + \sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3} + \sqrt{3} ) = 1.29663026289$

It follows that

$ t = \tan^{-1} \bigg( \dfrac{1}{y+1} \bigg) = 23.5292985676^\circ $

And

$ x = (y + 2) \sin t = 1.31607401295 $

Comment: Your answers are right. So, I’m trying to follow your logic. After "It follows that" [above] you give two expressions for cos t and sin t. How were the values for the denominators arrived at. I understand all before "It follows that."

Comment: $\cos t = 1 /\sqrt{ sec^2 t} = 1/\sqrt{ tan^2 t + 1 } $ and then $\sin t = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 t } $

Answer (score 3):

We know that $AD = y$, $CD = 1$, $BD = AD + 1 = y + 1$, and $BC = BD + CD = y + 2$.  Since $ABC$ is a right triangle, with $AC = x$ and $BC = y+2$, $AB = \sqrt{(y+2)^2 - x^2}$.  Because $\angle CAB = 90°$ and $\angle DAB = 45°$, $\angle CAD = 45°$ as well.

If we name $\angle ABC = \theta$, then $\angle ACB = 180° - 90° - \theta = 90° - \theta$.  Similarly, $\angle ADB = 180° - 45° - \theta = 135° - \theta$, and $\angle CDA = 180° - (135° - \theta) = \theta + 45°$.

Applying the law of sines to the upper left triangle, we get
$$\frac{1}{\sin 45°} = \frac{y}{\sin\left(90° - \theta\right)} = \frac{x}{\sin\left(45° + \theta\right)}$$
Because $\sin\left(90°-\theta\right) = \cos\theta$ and $\sin 45° = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$, the above is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} = \frac{y}{\cos\theta} \quad \Rightarrow \quad y = \sqrt{2} \cos \theta \tag{1}\label{1}$$
and to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} = \frac{x}{\sin\left(45° + \theta\right)} \quad \Rightarrow \quad x = \sqrt{2}\sin\left(45° + \theta\right) \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Applying the law of sines to the largest triangle, we know that
$$\frac{y + 2}{\sin 90°} = \frac{x}{\sin\theta} = \frac{\sqrt{(y+2)^2 - x^2}}{\sin\left(45° + \theta\right)}$$
Since $\sin 90° = 1$,
$$x = (y + 2) \sin \theta = \sqrt{2} \cos\theta \sin\theta + 2 \sin\theta \tag{3}\label{3}$$

Thus, the problem is now finding $\theta$.

---

If we combine $\eqref{2}$ and $\eqref{3}$, we have an equation only in $\theta$,
$$\sqrt{2}\sin\left(45° + \theta\right) = \sqrt{2} \cos\theta \sin\theta + 2 \sin\theta$$
Here, we can use the angle sum formula $\sin\left(x + y\right) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$, noting that $\sin 45° = \cos 45° = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$, and that $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} = 1$.  Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{2}\left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \cos \theta + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \sin \theta \right) &= \sqrt{2} \cos\theta \sin\theta + 2 \sin\theta \\
\Rightarrow \quad \cos\theta + \sin\theta &= \sqrt{2} \cos\theta \sin\theta + 2 \sin\theta \\
\end{aligned}$$
and finally
$$\Rightarrow \quad \cos\theta - \sin\theta = \sqrt{2} \cos\theta \sin\theta \tag{4}\label{4}$$
This can only be solved numerically ($\theta \approx 23.52930°$ for $0° \lt \theta \lt 90°$).

---

If we apply the Law of Sines to the lower right triangle:
$$\frac{y}{\sin\theta} = \frac{y+1}{\sin 45°} \left( = \frac{y+1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} \right) = \frac{\sqrt{(y+2)^2 - x^2}}{\sin\left(135°-\theta\right)}$$
we get
$$y = \frac{\sqrt{2}\sin\theta}{1 - \sqrt{2}\sin\theta}$$
giving us another way to calculate $\theta$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin\theta}{1 - \sqrt{2}\sin\theta} &= \sqrt{2} \cos \theta \\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{\sin\theta}{1 - \sqrt{2}\sin\theta} &= \cos\theta \\
\Rightarrow \quad \sin\theta &= \cos\theta - \sqrt{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta \\
\Rightarrow \quad \cos\theta - \sin\theta &= \sqrt{2}\sin\theta\cos\theta \\
\end{aligned}$$
which is the same expression as before.

---

If we add point $E$ directly below $D$ on line $AB$, then triangle $BDE$ is a right triangle, $AE = ED = y/\sqrt{2}$, $BD = y + 1$, and
$$BE = \sqrt{(y+1)^2 - \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{2} + 2 y + 1}$$
and
$$AB = AE+BE = \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{2} + 2 y + 1}$$
Comparing to $AB$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{(y+2)^2 - x^2} &= \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{2} + 2 y + 1} \\
\Rightarrow \quad x^2 &= (y + 2)^2 - \left( \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{2} + 2 y + 1} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 \\
\Rightarrow \quad x^2 &= 3 + 2 y - y \sqrt{y^2 + 4 y + 2} \\
\end{aligned}$$
and thus
$$x = \sqrt{ 3 + 2 y - y \sqrt{y^2 + 4 y + 2} } \tag{5}\label{5}$$

Because this is similar to the large triangle, $BD/ED = BC/AC$,
$$\frac{y + 1}{y\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} = \frac{y + 2}{x}$$
which simplifies to
$$x = \frac{y^2 + 2 y}{\sqrt{2}y + \sqrt{2}} \tag{6}\label{6}$$
Equating $\eqref{5}$ and $\eqref{6}$ we get
$$\sqrt{ 3 + 2 y - y \sqrt{y^2 + 4 y + 2} } = \frac{y^2 + 2 y}{\sqrt{2}y + \sqrt{2}}$$
which simplifies to
$$2 (y + 1)^2 \left( 3 + 2 y - y \sqrt{y^2 + 4 y + 2} \right) - (y^2 + 2 y)^2 = 0$$
but once again, there does not seem to be an algebraic solution, only a numerical one ($y \approx 1.296630$, and via $\eqref{6}$, $x \approx 1.316074$, corresponding to $\theta \approx 23.52930°$, noting that $\sqrt[4]{3} \approx 1.316074$, so the exact answer mentioned in the comments, $x = \sqrt[4]{3}$, definitely fits, and via $\eqref{6}$ $y = \sqrt{\sqrt{3/4}+1}+\sqrt[4]{3/4}-1$, which seems to be the solution to the simplified form).

---

So, there are several ways to obtain a *numerical* result, but you probably need to know some trigonometric trick (particular similar triangle) here to find the analytically solvable expression.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a vertical line through point $D$. Call the intersection with interval $AB$ point $E$. Also draw a horizontal line through point $D$. Call the intersection with interval $AC$ point $F$. This way the triangle $ABC$ is divided into a square with sides $AE = ED = DF = AF = L$ and with diagonal $y = AD = \sqrt{2} L$, plus the triangles $EBD$ and $FDC$. Furthermore let $\phi$ be the angle at point $B$.

Now it is given that $BD = AD + 1 = \sqrt{2}L+1$. From triangle $EBD$ we derive $L = BD \sin(\phi)$. From triangle $FDC$ we derive $L = \cos(\phi)$. Three equations to solve, with three unknowns.

Eliminating $BD$ we get $L = (\sqrt{2}L+1)\sin(\phi)$. Write this as $L - \sin(\phi) = \sqrt{2}L\sin(\phi)$. Squaring both sides and substituting $L = \cos(\phi)$ we get

$$2\sin^2(\phi)\cos^2(\phi) + 2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi) -1 =0$$

Using $\sin(2\phi) = 2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)$ and solving the resulting quadratic equation leads to:

$$\sin(2\phi) = -1 + \sqrt{3}$$

Therefore the exact solution is:

$$\phi = 0.5 \arcsin(-1 + \sqrt{3})$$

$$x = \cos(\phi) + \sin(\phi) = 1.316074...$$
$$y = \sqrt{2}\cos(\phi) = 1.296630... $$

Comment: I think the last line of your solution should be y= √2cos(Φ) A great approach/solution

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Sage gave up on this, but
Using the figure from Piquito, and the set of equations below,
Geogebra CAS solved the following:[image]
$$\begin{align}
X^2+w^2&=(y+2)^2\quad &\Rightarrow Pythagoras\\
X&=(y+2)\cdot\sin(t)\quad &\Rightarrow \text{sine definition}\\
-2yX\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+y^2+X^2 &=1^2 \quad &\Rightarrow\ \text{law of cosines}\\
-2\cdot y\cdot w\cdot \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+y^2+w^2 &=(y+1)^2 \quad &\Rightarrow \text{law of cosines}\\
\end{align}
$$
No analytic solution was found.
$$
\begin{align}
X &= 1.316074012952\\
y &= 1.296630262902\\
w &= 3.022535406347\\
t &=0.410663730686793 = 23.52929856790132 degrees
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Re-thinking the figure for greater symmetry ...

> Let the angle bisector at right $\angle A$ meet hypotenuse $\overline{BC}$ at $D$, and define $m:=|BD|$, $n:=|CD|$ (with $m\geq n > 0$). The problem imposes the condition $|AD|=m-n$.
>
> [image]

- The [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) tells us that, for some $\lambda>0$, we can write $$|AB|=\lambda m \qquad |AC|=\lambda n \tag1$$
- The Pythagorean Theorem then tells us
  $$(m+n)^2 = (\lambda m)^2+(\lambda n)^2 \quad\to\quad
  2 m n = (\lambda^2-1) (m^2 + n^2) \tag2$$
- Finally, [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) tells us
  $$\begin{align}
  (\lambda m)^2 n+(\lambda n)^2m &=(m+n)\left((m-n)^2+mn\right)\\[4pt]
  \to\qquad(\lambda^2+1) m n &= m^2+n^2\tag3
  \end{align}$$

From here, combining equations via $(\lambda^2-1)(3)-(2)$ yields
$$(\lambda^4-3)mn = 0 \qquad\to\qquad \lambda = \sqrt[4]{3} \tag{$\star$}$$

---

For the problem at hand: $n=1$, so that
$$x:=\lambda n = \sqrt[4]{3} = 1.3160\ldots$$ and (solving quadratic $(2)$, and using the fact that $m\geq n$ to establish that the "$\pm$" should be "$+$")
$$m =\frac12 \left(1 + \sqrt{3} \pm \sqrt[4]3\sqrt{2}\right) \quad\to\quad y := m-n =\frac12 \left(-1 + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt[4]3\sqrt{2}\right) = 1.2966\ldots$$